# Property taking its type from a generic method

Tags: c#, generics, methods

In my spare time, I'm creating a small business framework that I can reuse for my school projects. I suppose it would be similar to a dumbed down CSLA, if that can give you an idea.

I'm having a bit of trouble with the business rule class though. Here's what it looks like right now :

```
public class Rule
{
    public string PropertyName { get; }
    public string Description { get; }
    public Func<object, bool> ValidationRule { get; }

    public Rule(string propertyName, string message, Func<object, bool> validationRule)
    {
        this.PropertyName = propertyName;
        this.Description = description;
        this.ValidationRule = validationRule;
    }

    public bool IsBroken(object value)
    {
        return ValidationRule(value);
    }
}
```

I'm not a huge fan of the boxing and unboxing I'm doing when I'm checking to see if the rule is broken (value can be any type).

Of course, I could just make the whole class generic and have my IsBroken function take an object of type T (probably a better idea than using objects anyway), but I was wondering if it would be possible to do something similar to the following :

```
public class Rule
{
    public Func<T, bool> ValidationRule { get; }
    public bool IsBroken<T>(T value)
    {
        return ValidationRule(value);
    }
}
```

Without declaring the class with a generic type?

Any other tips are welcome.

Comment: The *only* way to share introduced generic types across methods/properties is to move them to the (or "a") class declaration. In this case it seems appropriate. Then, also implement an interface, say `IRule` that will allow support for "untyped object access" (and allow shoving these rules into mixed `Rule<any>` collections or whatnot). Then either the specific `Rule<T>` can be used, or a less refined `IRule` can be used, where it it not possible to deal with `Rule<T>`.

Comment: If I am not mistaken, you can use `typeof` or something in the `System.Type` class to determine the type, and simply pass the object as a `dynamic` and cast it.

Comment: If you know the T while calling IsBroken, you probably know it while instantiating a Rule object, why don't you just change it to `Rule<T>` ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I was wondering if it would be possible to do something similar to the following :
>   [...]
>   Without declaring the class with a generic type?

No, it's not possible. How would the compiler and/or the runtime know what type is T for property declaration?

Comment: Check out my edit - methods are ok to be generic in non-generic class, but properties aren't.

Comment: The `dynamic` keyword forces verification at runtime for all related functions, bypassing that restriction.

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov It doesn't matter here. Even if it were possible to introduce a new generic type for the property, it would be a *different* type .. imagine if there are two methods (which by the post can introduce new generic types) that both introduce `T`; it is a *different* `T` for each method.

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov Presumably there wasn't enough use-case/payoff to allow `Func<T,T> Prop<T> { get;set; }` (where T is a "property generic" in this *hypothetical* code) or similar definitions over properties .. here is a [post "Why aren’t there generic properties in C#?"](http://newcome.wordpress.com/2011/02/18/why-arent-there-generic-properties-in-c/) that asks similar questions.

Comment: @pst, I'm not sure I follow what you are suggesting about my edit... Your link/comment seem to say the same: one can't have generic properties in non-generic class unlike methods.

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov 1) one cannot *introduce* a generic parameter for a property (as stated) 2) even if one could it wouldn't matter here because it would be *only* for that property. The only way to *share* a generic parameter type is to move it to the class level. That is; `T f<T>() {}; T g<T>() {}` is *no different* from `Tf f<Tf>() {}; Tg g<Tg>() {}`, because `T` (or `Tf` or `Tg`) are *only introduced for that method*; they are not related in any way.

Answer (score 0):

declare Rule class as generic is the only way moreover it is interesting for you because you will want to set constraint on your T generic

```
 public class Rule<T>
    {
        public Func<T, bool> ValidationRule { get; }
        public bool IsBroken<T>(T value)
        {
            return ValidationRule(value);
        }
    }
```